# Tkinter widget (label) borderwidth

Tags: tkinter

I'm confused about that " is it necessary to give the relief value into the Tkinter widget such as a label to make the border around it.

I have used this

```
label_config = {'bg':"#cafcf6",'fg':'Blue', 'height':10, 'width':30, 'borderwidth':5}

south_label = tk.Label(root, text="south", anchor=tk.S, cnf=label_config)
south_label.grid(row=2, column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
```

In this code, the border doesn't appear but when I give relief in the label_config I can see the border so, I think that to make the border we need to specify relief style also, is it necessary?

```
 label_config = {'bg':"#cafcf6",'fg':'Blue', 'height':10, 'width':30, 'borderwidth':5,relief:"RIDGE"}
    
    south_label = tk.Label(root, text="south", anchor=tk.S, cnf=label_config)
    south_label.grid(row=2, column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
```

Comment: The border exists, but the default relief is tk.FLAT

Comment: You don't have to use `"RELIEF"` you can just use the reseved variable:  `relief=tk.RELIEF`. Since you did not just import all of tkinter to your program but loaded it as `tk.` you will have to use the name of the module when calling an object.